# Living cost in Al-khobar, Saudi Arabia

Tags: cost-of-living, costs

Can anyone give some good guidance about a living cost in Al-khobar, KSA?

such as rent decent 2-3 bedroom house/apartment, bills, transportation, cost of car etc.

I am currently living in the UK, and in the process in considering a job offer.

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you looking to live in a compound with other westerners, or in a "normal" place with locals?

Comment: I am not sure yet. Would you be able to give some kind of rough estimate on both options? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Numbeo](https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/in/Al-Khobar) gives some estimates about prices of food, renting apartments etc. in Al-Khobar. Based on that you can estimate your monthly needs.

You can also [compare cost of living](https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/compare_cities.jsp?country1=United%20States&country2=Saudi%20Arabia&city1=New%20York%2C%20NY&city2=Al%20Khobar&tracking=getDispatchComparison) between chosen cities to compare prices with your current lifestyle.

Their estimates seems to be fresh and updated, as they say

> These data are based on 487 entries in the past 18 months from 53 different contributors. Last update: March, 2017